# How to redirect Mediawiki Short URL with no title to Main Page?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, mediawiki

I've implemented Short URL for my mediawiki and I have these in htaccess that works:

```
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?w/images/thumb/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2 [L,QSA,B]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?w/images/thumb/archive/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2&archived=1 [L,QSA,B]
```

How do I redirect page urls that doesnt have page title to Main_Page? Like redirecting mysite.com/wiki/ to the mysite.com/w/index.php/Main_Page? In the MW Apache rewrite Manual it says this:

> Optionally, you can include a rule to show the Main Page on the path
>   itself, to simplify navigation when people visit urls without a page
>   title specified:
>
> `# Redirect / to Main Page RewriteRule ^/*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]`

When I add the above, the main domain address gets redirected to wiki which I dont want since I have a different Home Page and not wiki. I only want to redirect the address that looks like mysite.com/wiki

I tried this rewrite but it doesnt work.

```
RewriteRule ^/?wiki/?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
```

Obviously I got something wrong. Can someone look at this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This redirect rule should automatically take care of redirecting urls with no page title like /wiki/ to the wiki/Main_Page too:

```
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
```

It wasnt working for me before since there was other rewrite rules before this. It worked once I move this rewrite rule to the top before all other rewrite rules.